# Flex - how to detect event when a DateField is edited

Tags: apache-flex, events, flash-builder, datefield

How can I detect when a user changes a date field - specifically when they TYPE the date as I have set it to editable:

```
<mx:FormItem label="Assigned" x="220" y="59">
        <mx:DateField formatString="YYYY-MM-DD" id="clinicianAssignedDateInput" editable="true" text="@{this._currentEditEncounter.clinicianAssignedDate}" toolTip="format: YYYY-MM-DD" change="clinicianAssignedDateInput_dataChangeHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
```

The change event seems to only throw when using the calendar pop-up.  It is not thrown when the user manually types in to the field.

I also tried dataChange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works - I used the focusOut="" event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible unless you extend the component and change the functionality; just add an event listener (change event) to the textinput and dispatch another event within the component.

Personally if I were you, I'd try to use Spark alternatives.  There's no official one, but I [found this](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2010/01/spark_datefield_and_colorpicke.html).